# A way to specify and initialize the type of a map's values?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, initialization

I want to count all the words in a line of text.  I'm using a map to do this, with the words for keys and integers for values. I don't know how to tell Ruby that all the values will be integers. It forces me to put an ugly branching inside my iterator's block:

```
# in the constructor
@individual_words = {}

def count_words_from( text_line )
  text_line.each do |line|
    line.scan(/\p{Word}+/)
    .reject{ |string| string =~ /\d/ }
    .each do |word|
      if @individual_words[ word ] == nil then   # This is ugly
        @individual_words[ word ] = 1            # This is ugly as well
      else
        @individual_words[ word ] += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In simple, I'd like to do something like this Java line:

```
Map<String, Integer> individualWords;
```

to avoid having to change the type of the first occurence of a word from `Nil` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set a default value in your hash like this:

```
individual_words = Hash.new(0)
```

Then when you come across a word, whether its key is in the hash or not, all you have to do is:

```
individual_words[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this

```
@individual_words[word] ||= 0
@individual_words[word] += 1
```

`||=` ensures that the value gets set if it's not truthy (ie. nil)